# (carrierwave gem is using)rails 4 converter app text to usfm file is uploaded but unable to download the file giving error? i am new in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**This is my controller** 
    class PostAttachmentsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_post_attachment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

```
  def index
    @post_attachments = PostAttachment.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
    @post_attachment = PostAttachment.new
  end


  def show


  end



  def new
    @post_attachment = PostAttachment.new
  end


  def edit
  end


  def create
    @post_attachment = PostAttachment.new(post_attachment_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post_attachment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post_attachment, notice: 'Post attachment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post_attachment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post_attachment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post_attachment.update(post_attachment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post_attachment.post, notice: 'Post attachment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post_attachment }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post_attachment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @post_attachment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to post_attachments_url, notice: 'Post attachment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def download
    send_file '#{Rails.root}/uploads/post_attachment/#{file.id}'
  end

  private

    def set_post_attachment
      @post_attachment = PostAttachment.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_attachment_params
      params.require(:post_attachment).permit(:convert_t, :post_id, :avatar)
    end
```

end

**My show page**

```
 <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
            <table class="table">
          <thead class="thead">
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>File Name</th>
              <th>Original</th>
              <th>Converted</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody class="tbody">
              <tr>
                <td><%= @post_attachment.id %></td>
                <td><%= File.basename(@post_attachment.avatar.url) %></td>
                <td><%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-download'></i> Download".html_safe, File.basename(@post_attachment.avatar.url) %></td>
                <td><%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-download'></i> Download".html_safe, File.basename(@post_attachment.avatar.url) %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Home', root_path, class: 'btn btn-xs btn-info' %></td>

              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

**Model**
    class PostAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
       mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
       belongs_to :post
    end

**routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :post_attachments
  resources :posts 
  root 'post_attachments#index'
  match "/uploads/:id/:basename.:extension", :controller => "post_attachments", :action => "download", via: :get
```

end